Jenkins SSH Agent throws error "Found unhandled java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception: Range [13, -1) out of bounds for length 0
I have this simple Jenkins Pipeline using SSH Agent
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage("Backup") {
            steps {
                sshagent (credentials: ["ssh-key"]) {
                    sh 'ssh administrator@192.168.15.5 "ls -la /path/to/directory"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But unfortunately, getting console error log

Started by user Users Name
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Project (Pipeline)
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Backup)
[Pipeline] sshagent
[ssh-agent] Using credentials administrator@*.*.*.*
$ ssh-agent
[Pipeline] // sshagent
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: d9b0b12b-96e5-4e30-9228-fe4ad3ef72ca
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [13, -1) out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:349)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4865)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2834)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.exec.ExecRemoteAgent.getAgentValue(ExecRemoteAgent.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.exec.ExecRemoteAgent.parseAgentEnv(ExecRemoteAgent.java:130)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.exec.ExecRemoteAgent.<init>(ExecRemoteAgent.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentStepExecution.initRemoteAgent(SSHAgentStepExecution.java:121)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentStepExecution.start(SSHAgentStepExecution.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:323)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1295)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:105)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:7)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:673)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:402)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:672)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:551)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:550)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:450)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:449)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:281)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:488)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:487)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:280)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:593)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:592)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:278)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:362)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:361)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:267)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:625)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:624)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:265)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:450)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:449)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:260)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:147)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:180)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:423)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Finished: FAILURE

I have successfully tried establishing connection between Jenkins Server and Remote Server without Password Authentication involved.

Upon checking on Pipeline Steps, it shows checked status.

I have tried removing the commands to simplify more. sh 'ssh administrator@*.*.*.* "ls -la /path/to/directory"'. But error still persists.
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage("Backup") {
            steps {
                sshagent (credentials: ["ssh-key"]) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I have double checked and recreated Jenkins SSH Credential already.
I have tried adding and removing the following on Jenkins Server > Environment Variable > Path
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

Try just sh 'ssh administrator@192.168.15.5 ls -la /path/to/directory'
